# Outlook meeting cancelling using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

There are instances when we forget to cancel a meeting which we scheduled, maybe due to absence of someone important, or maybe due to lack of time. But in many cases we forget to cancel the meeting from outlook. So, I am looking for a VBA code which will ask the organizer of a meeting if the meeting is good to go, or if it is to be cancelled, and will send out a cancellation mail if it is to be cancelled. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What Luca is indicating is that on SO we value people first trying their best to figure something out on their own, then asking a question about the specific thing they are stuck on.

Comment: I am completely new to VBA. I have searched for VBA codes which will help me do the same, but to no avail. The closest I came to is a code which will send reminder's for meetings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using the code from @alina as well as some other macro's from around the web, I came up with a solution for the same which i am sharing here.

```
Public WithEvents objReminders As Outlook.Reminders

Sub Initialize_handler()

   Set objReminders = Application.Reminders
End Sub

Private Sub objReminders_ReminderFire(ByVal ReminderObject As reminder)

 Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
 Dim oNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
 Dim oApptItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem
 Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
 Dim oMeetingoApptItem As Outlook.MeetingItem
 Dim oObject As Object
 Dim iUserReply As VbMsgBoxResult
 Dim sErrorMessage As String
 MsgBox (VBA.Time)
On Error Resume Next
 ' check if Outlook is running
 Set oApp = GetObject("Outlook.Application")
 If Err <> 0 Then
   'if not running, start it
   Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 End If

 On Error GoTo Err_Handler
 Set oNameSpace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set oFolder = oNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

 For Each oObject In oFolder.Items
   If oObject.Class = olAppointment Then
     Set oApptItem = oObject
        If ReminderObject.Caption = oApptItem.Subject Then
        If oApptItem.Organizer = Outlook.Session.CurrentUser Then
        iUserReply = MsgBox("Meeting found:-" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
            & Space(4) & "Date/time (duration): " & Format(oApptItem.Start, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn") _
            & " (" & oApptItem.Duration & "mins)" & Space(10) & vbCrLf _
            & Space(4) & "Subject: " & oApptItem.Subject & Space(10) & vbCrLf _
            & Space(4) & "Location: " & oApptItem.Location & Space(10) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
            & "Do you want to continue with the meeting?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1, "Meeting confirmation")
       If iUserReply = vbNo Then
            oApptItem.MeetingStatus = olMeetingCanceled
            oApptItem.Save
            oApptItem.Send
            oApptItem.Delete
            End If
          End If
     End If
   End If

 Next oObject

 Set oApp = Nothing
 Set oNameSpace = Nothing
 Set oApptItem = Nothing
 Set oFolder = Nothing
 Set oObject = Nothing

 Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
 sErrorMessage = Err.Number & " " & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/564254-how-do-i-delete-outlook-appointment-item-visual-basic-applications.html)

```
Public Function DeleteAppointments(ByVal subjectStr As String)

    Dim oOL As New Outlook.Application
    Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim oAppointments As Object
    Dim oAppointmentItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim iReply As VbMsgBoxResult

    Set oNS = oOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oAppointments = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    Count = oAppointments.Items.Count 'for test purposes

    For Each oAppointmentItem In oAppointments.Items
        If InStr(oAppointmentItem.Subject, subjectStr) > 0 Then
        iReply = msgbox("Appointment found:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
            & Space(4) & "Date/time: " & Format(oAppointmentItem.Start, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn") & vbCrLf _
            & Space(4) & "Subject: " & oAppointmentItem.Subject & Space(10) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
            & "Delete this appointment?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton2, "Delete Appointment?")
        If iReply = vbYes Then oAppointmentItem.Delete
            oAppointmentItem.Delete
        End If
    Next

    Set oAppointmentItem = Nothing
    Set oAppointments = Nothing
    Set oNS = Nothing
    Set oOL = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. But I have one more doubt regarding this. Please bear with me, as I am completely new to VBA. So, the doubt is, how do you call this whole macro? Also, where will you give the value for the variable "subjectStr", which I guess is the checking variable in this case. 

Thanks again for the code! :)